# Is there a way to set significant digit display in a flextable?

Tags: r, flextable

I am trying to set significant digit display for a [flextable](/questions/tagged/flextable) object.

```
# Select data from a dataframe
ft <- flextable(data, col_keys = c(1,2,3,4)) 
# adjust digit display in columns 3 and 4 of flextable
ft <- colformat_num(ft, j = c(3,4), digits = 4)
```

However, the digits argument in this snippet sets digits **after** the decimal point, as opposed to rounding a number to n significant digits. Here is a sample formula from Excel:

> =ROUND(number,digits-(1+INT(LOG10(ABS(number)))))

Can this be reproduced in the `flextable` command? Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 3):

You can create a formatter function and use set_formatter:

```
library(flextable)

round_and_format <- function(number) {
  rr <- round(number,digits-(1+as.integer(log10(abs(number)))))
  as.character(rr)
}

ft <- flextable(head(iris))
ft <- set_formatter(ft, Sepal.Length = round_and_format, Sepal.Width = round_and_format)
ft <- autofit(ft)
print(ft)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The answer from David worked, but after these small corrections.

For it to work the function needs to add an abs before the log10 function and there is an = sign after digits:

```
round_and_format <- function(number) {
  rr <- round(number,digits=(1+as.integer(abs(log10(abs(number))))))
  as.character(rr)
}
```